# problem with \frac

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I am trying to get this equation:

[image]

But this is the result:

[image]

this is my code:

```
\begin{equation*}
adds =\frac{p}{(1-p)} =\frac{ la probabilitée de présence d'un caractéréstique}{la probabilitée de l'absence de caractéréstique}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: If you want text in an equation, use `\text{whatever}`.

Comment: I just add \text{mytext} to fix it . thank you @lanThompson